# Linux c++: apis vs /proc files?

Tags: c++, linux, battery, procfs, disk-partitioning

Im working on an app to collect and send various bits of system info (partition space/free, laptop battery info, etc). Im not having much success getting this information in the form of direct c++ api.. though its all available via files in /proc (or similar).

So - I'm wondering whether reading/parsing these files in my c++ app is the appropriate way to get this info or should I keep trying to discover APIs? ( NOTE: I am working with statvfs ).

So far it looks like it's easier to gather this sort of info in Win32. Seems strange.

Comment: The procinfo source has some hints as to how to parse each file http://svn.tabris.net/repos/procinfo-ng/trunk/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best practice *by far* to stick with an API in the following order of precedence.

- Your language API (not much help for you here, but say for strings, a C99 string function is better to use than a library string facility specified by a Posix or other OS standard.)
- Posix operating software APIs
- Documented kernel API's
- Undocumented kernel APIs (at least these will break, say, ioctl users if they change, so they probably won't change)
- `/proc`
- `/dev/kmem`, `/dev/mem`

There is no reason to believe that `/proc` trolling will be portable or even the same from release to release. Not every system will even have a `/proc` mounted!

Having said all that, it ***is*** much easier to just scrape stuff off of `/proc` and if it's the only available interface then you should go ahead and use it.qa

Finally, the ordering of the last two isn't completely clear, because `/proc` isn't available for a post-mortem kernel crash dump analysis, but tools that can peek in the core  dump will still work.

Comment: There *is* no other interface than /proc for a lot of information in Linux. And for version changes, *pay attention* to /proc outputs that contain a version ID. And in multi-column /proc outputs don't assume it won't get more columns in future!

Comment: And that's why I included it in the list of places to go.

Comment: +1 but I'd add above `/proc` utilities in the repository which use `/proc` in the correct system-specific way (such as `procps`, `systune`, `linuxinfo`)

Comment: procfs **is** a [documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) [kernel API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), so it should be above the "Undocumented kernel APIs" line in your list.

Answer (score 1):

I though that /proc was the API (everything is a file...)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, a lot of Linux systems information is in `/proc`. And you're correct that there often isn't a C API for retrieving that information (though there is usually a shell command if you're inclined to stick with bash instead of C++). In the worst-case scenario, you might be stuck parsing through `/proc`, though you might be able to get some sample code in the form of open-source shell commands for the particular item you want.

Comment: I guess I just want "someone who knows" to say "there aint no stinkin' api for that". Im fine with parsing the various files if that's what is assumed to be correct.

Comment: @jyeargers Most tasks have no stickin' API. Sample code from open-source projects are usually the way forward. (Or just `strace` the shell command you want to emulate and see what files it opens if that's all you need.)