# Getting signal strength of received packet in wireless OCB mode

Tags: c, linux, wireless, signal-strength

I am using OCB mode based on ath9k driver for my wireless connections between different nodes. I need to know the signal strength of received packets in my user-space application to do some calculation based on that. In order to communicate I am using socket APIs and udp packets.

So, here is the question:  Is there any function or API in C to get signal strength of a received packet in a user-space application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the signal strengh "of a received packet" really makes sense, but you can get some information on the wifi signal where you are connected by reading `/proc/net/wireless`

```
$ cat /proc/net/wireless 
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   69.  -41.  -256        0      0      0      1    274        0
```

Generally speaking, `/proc` provides runtime information about your system. Technically speaking, if you wish to read this from a C program you should probably try to find if there is an API for this, otherwise read/open/close the file and parse its content. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650998/linux-c-apis-vs-proc-files) for details about reading the /proc filesystem.

Comment: In cantrast to AP or Ad-hoc mode, in OCB mode we don't connect to a network, I mean in OCB we are outside of BSS and have no associated connection to be searched we have to find the signal strength of received packet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cfg80211`, see http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211/